# Sd card not recognise in any pc ( but recognised in mobiles)

Tags: sd-card

My 32 gb memory card is readable in any mobile but it is not at all detecting in any pc or laptop. I can view, delete, add anything from any mobiles but when I tried to insert the same sd card to different laptops even using different card reader then also it not at all detecting. How to fix this?

Comment: The sd card is corrupted.you need to change it before it damages your cell.

Comment: @dannystech How do you get that idea? 1) If it works fine in any mobile, why should it be corrupted? 2) How would a corrupted SD card (assuming it really *is* corrupted) "damage your cell"?

Comment: What OS is running on those PCs / laptops? Are they not detecting the card as such, or can they simply not mount it?

Answer (score 0):

According to you description of the situation, either of the two thing could have happened:

1. Your SDcard is formatted in a way that windows (assuming you use that) doesn't recognise. Ext4 is really common amongst Linux device (including android) but is not recognised by windows. If you can connect to the SDcard using a mobile in MTP mode, I recommend you do that and then format the card to FAT32 for compatibility with windows. Alternatively, you could use an Linux Live partition to use the card and format it.
2. Your readers might be broke (unlikely to happen on multiple devices suddenly in such short interval but a possibility). Try using a different card to confirm. This will also be signified by drive probably not appearing in Disk Management.

> To format a drive in windows:
>
> 1. Press `Win Key + x` and then `Disk Management` on windows 8 and above. In Earlier windows, right click `computer` > `Manage` and then select
>      `disk management` in the left panel.
> 2. Right-click on the SDcard partition to format and click on Format.
> 3. Select the file system as FAT32. Click OK to format the drive.